# How to call solr server from python using unix socket instead of localhost?

Tags: solr, unix-socket

I am querying using solr search engine in my webapp. But right now I am calling solr server from python using

```
 "http://localhost:8983/solr/select?q="
```

But I heard using unix socket instead helps reduce tcp/ip overhead. How to go about it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of the popular application containers support connections over local unix sockets, and usually for a good reason; it's a very, very, very small part of the request/response cycle, so unless you're actually seeing issues from tcp/ip setup and teardown, there should be very little reason for this.

Client libraries does not support local unix sockets either, as they exclusively talk TCP/IP to the server (and assumes an URL as an endpoint).

You can use EmbeddedSolr to integrate Solr directly into a Java project and use it without any request overhead, but the overhead from a search application will be small compared with the time taken to perform the actual search and handling the application container.